# Can't get Location in iOS (GEOErrorDomain Code=-204)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to display a map and drop a pin using `MKMapView`. This is my code

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } }; 
region.center.latitude = 37.47 ;
region.center.longitude = 122.26;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

But I get the error below

```
<GEOTileSource: 0x8e4c160>: Error downloading tiles Server Error: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-204 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -204.)" UserInfo=0x88990f0 
{UnderlyingErrors=(
"Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-204 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -204.)\" UserInfo=0x885b570 {IncompleteResponse=Asked for 2 tiles but only got 0 back}",
"Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-204 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -204.)\" UserInfo=0x8890a50 {IncompleteResponse=Asked for 6 tiles but only got 0 back}"
)}
```

I am not finding any reference to what `GEOErrorDomain Code=-204` is. Please help me out.

Comment: same error here.  It seems to happen only in simulator, it works in device..  reserch on proccess :)

Comment: The same code works fine on iOS 5 simulator. I tried running it with XCode45-DP2 with iOS6 SDK and get this error.

Comment: For me , this happens in the device & not the Simulator

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to XCode DP4 and all seems to be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

That was an error with the beta version. I would get that occasionally because of how they are loading the location tiles. Assuming it is working ok on beta 4, I wouldn't worry too much about. There are a few location/map issues they are still working out, so I wouldn't be surprised to find more by the time the beta period is done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case it only happen when closing the UIViewController before the map completed loading all tiles.
The fix was to set the mapView (MKMapView) delegate to nil when closing the view controller.

```
mapView.delegate = nil;
```