# ios6 mapkit error simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

after updating to ios6 and running my app in ios6 Simulator i get following error:

```
   2012-09-24 16:58:47.988 Pigeons[628:c07] <GEOTileSource: 0x99aa380>: 
Error downloading     tiles Server Error: Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-204 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -204.)" UserInfo=0x19989ff0 {UnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=GEOErrorDomain Code=-204 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -204.)\""
)}
```

Has anyone got any idea why this error occurs. 
On device or older simulator the error doesn't occur.

Greetings,
Jaco

Comment: Look at my answer at: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16330806/2199996)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems this is just some internal problems downloading tiles from server for the new Apple maps. I also see similar errors, but they do not affect anything and are not related to your code.

Comment: Thanks, hope the will fix it soon though...kinda annoying

Comment: I just got this too after upgrading to ARC. I doubt it is something with Apple. Anyone find a solution to it?